# Vertices not moving to predicted location when calculated with camera function

Tags: javascript, 3d, logic, game-engine, p5.js

I am creating a 3D game from scratch using P5.js. However, after the triangles vertices have gone behind the cameras plane, it flips and goes to the wrong spot.

I realise this is because I am dividing by the z value, and as z goes negative it flips the value, however I am not sure how I can resolve this. I have tried absolute valuing the z value but it just stops working. If anyone has any idea as a way I can fix this? Thank you!

code: https://editor.p5js.org/JamesB_/sketches/5w4z2fWs6